# Как сгладить движение камеры?

Tags: unity3d

Привет. Есть такой код для камеры -

```
float xRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
Vector3 cameraRotation = new Vector3(xRot, 0, 0) * lookSensitivity;
playerMotor.RotateCamera(cameraRotation);
```

playerMotor -

```
private Vector3 cameraRotation = Vector3.zero;
public void RotateCamera(Vector3 _cameraRotation)
{
    cameraRotation = _cameraRotation;
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    PerformRotation();
}
```

Таким образом пытаюсь сгладить движение камеры -

```
void PerformRotation()
{        
    if (cam != null)
    {
        var orgRotation = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        cameraRotation = Vector3.Lerp(orgRotation, cameraRotation, cameraSmothens);
        cam.transform.Rotate(-cameraRotation);
    }
}
```

Но  Lerp не работает, какое бы я значение времени не установил, почему?
cameraRotation - это ось(мыши) X.

Answer (score 1):

Используем в работе вот такой не хитрый скрипт. Все что нужно навешать его на вашу камеру и задать ссылку на объект за которым двигаться. При необходимости можно еще задать объект на который надо смотреть

```
public class FollowMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target = null;
    public bool Smoothing = true;
    public Transform LookObject = null;
    public bool KeepDistance = true;
    public float TimeMoving = 0.5f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Target != null)
        {
            if (Smoothing)
            {
                float distance = 0f;

                if (LookObject != null)
                {
                    distance = (transform.position - LookObject.position).magnitude;
                }
                transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, Target.position, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Target.rotation, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving);
                if (LookObject != null && KeepDistance)
                {
                    Vector3 direction = transform.position - LookObject.position;
                    if (distance > direction.magnitude)
                        transform.position = LookObject.position + direction.normalized * distance;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Target.position;
                transform.rotation = Target.rotation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мне не нужно чтобы камера за чем то следила. Вот видео как камера сейчас работает - streamable.com/8o9y8, а вот как должно - streamable.com/r7nxa . Я, просто, хочу чтобы камера двигалась как на втором видео

Comment: ну так для этого скрипт и написан. Создаем объект в точке где у нас персонаж, и поворачиваем его резко сразу в нужную сторону, а скрипт следит за этим объектом и плавно поворачивается в нужную точку. Так что все скачки и дерганья за счет того что мы их не видим через этот фильтр пройдут незаметно

Comment: вы уверены, что нужный мне скрипт скинули?) Он же просто ограничивает углы обзора по оси Y. Чем больше TimeMoving, тем больше сглаживания при достижении ограничений.

Comment: скрипт меняет позицию и поворот плавно или нет в зависимости от ваших настроек, где вы увидели ограничение на углы обзора?

Comment: здесь - https://streamable.com/6l5lg

Comment: покажите настройки с которым запускаете скрипт)